# Comparing Domainaccounts via Powershell and write differences if needed

Tags: powershell

I recently started with the WPS. So far I think it's totally awesome.

Although I just started with some small scripts to get error logs and running services, I do now have a little bigger project ahead of me where I'm kinda stuck now.
Guess I'm missing a basic understanding of the powershell here.

I have two different domains with both DCs running on Win Server 2012.
The idea now is to set up a scheduled task and to compare all domainaccounts of domain1 with domain2 via powershell and if there are any different infos in the account of domain2 (like the phone number) to write these differences back to the account of domain1.

A unique indentifier in both domains is always the logon name of a user. (It's a personal ID number).
Im running the script locally on the first DC. To get all the fields I want to compare I'm using the following command:

```
$user1 = get-aduser -filter * -Properties City,CN,Company,Country,CountryCode,Department,Description,DisplayName,EmailAddress,GivenName,HomePage,HomePhone,Initials,MobilePhone,Name,Office,OfficePhone,Organization,OtherName,PostalCode,SamAccountName,sn,State,StreetAddress,Surname,Title
```

The big question now is: what to do next and how?
Should I export the results into a .csv/.xml file first? How to search for all the exported SamAccountNames in domain2, compare the results and write the differences (if any) back to the account in domain1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
$name = ...

$dc1 = foo.example.com
$dc2 = bar.example.net

$attributes = 'City', 'CN', 'Company', 'Country', 'CountryCode', 'Department',
              'Description', 'DisplayName', 'EmailAddress', 'GivenName',
              'HomePage', 'HomePhone', 'Initials', 'MobilePhone', 'Name',
              'Office', 'OfficePhone', 'Organization', 'OtherName', 'PostalCode',
              'SamAccountName', 'sn', 'State', 'StreetAddress', 'Surname',
              'Title'

$user1 = Get-ADUser -Identity $name -Properties $attributes -Server $dc1
$user2 = Get-ADUser -Identity $name -Properties $attributes -Server $dc2

$modified = @{}
$attributes | ? { $user1.$_ -ne $user2.$_ } | % {
  $modified[$_] = $user2.$_
}

if ($modified.Count -gt 0) {
  Set-ADUser -Identity $name -Replace $modified -Server $dc1
}
```

Comment: yes, definetely a more elegant option by putting everything into variables. thanks
But the ISE is now showing me a lots of errors. I can't run the script with even just one attribute.

City : The term 'City' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\ps11.ps1:8 char:15
+ $attributes = City
+  ~~~~   
  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (City:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Server'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or 
empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\ps11.ps1:12 char:69
+ $user1 = Get-ADUser -Identity $name -Properties $attributes -Server $dc1
+                                                                     ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Server'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or 
empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\ps11.ps1:13 char:69
+ $user2 = Get-ADUser -Identity $name -Properties $attributes -Server $dc2
+                                                                     ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: @StUffz My bad. The property names need to be put in quotes. Fixed.

Comment: okay great. that works just fine in reading the attributes. The next problem im now facing is with the -replace and $modified variable.
From my understanding the $modified is now a PSObject. Does this one have to be converted or anything?

I do now get:

Comment: Set-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Replace'. The argument is null or an element of the argument collection contains 
a null value.
At C:\ps11.ps1:30 char:37
+ Set-ADUser -Identity $name -Replace $modified
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Comment: @StUffz `$modified` contains a hashtable with the names and values of attributes that were different between the two user objects. If there were no attributes with different values, the hashtable will be empty, though, so you need to check that.

Comment: sorry my bad. you did indeed understand correctly.
I somehow managed to copy another error of one of my previous trials.

As of now I'm just getting the following:
Set-ADUser : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist
Parameter name: Office

It doesn't matter if I delete these attributes, because it's always complaining about another attribute then. So I delete Office, and it's saying that the email does not exist and so on...

Comment: @StUffz To get the proper attribute names, enable "Advanced Features" in `dsa.msc`. That will (among other things) add a tab "Attribute Editor" to the properties dialogs. That tab shows the attribute names as they are stored in AD. `Get-ADUser` creates several additional properties derived from the attributes for convenience. If you need both, you should create a mapping (another hashtable) between attribute names and corresponding properties and use the former for `Get-ADUser and the latter for comparing attributes between the user objects.

Comment: yay thanks. thats explaining a lot. It works perfectly now. Thanks. Now I just have to get it to work so that it gets all the Users and not just a predefined one. But I think that I can manage alone. I owe you one!

PS: Isn't the $fltr = { SamAccountName -eq $name } a little unnecessary for the current code?

Comment: Ah, yes. I had originally intended a slightly different `Get-ADUser` request and forgot to remove the variable. Fixed.

Comment: an addition from my side. To have an output if there are no changes, i used `if ($modified.Count -ge 1)` to include an else with a write-host